# Sort remote XML file by field

Tags: php, sorting, simplexml

I need to sort an XML file that is accessed from a remote server and accessed by simpleXML like this (its the approved way of accessing the file in the spec from the provider - so can't be changed)

```
$propertylist = simplexml_load_file("http://link.to/file.xml?accesskey");
```

I need to sort on a `$propertylist->price` high to low, without piping the XML contents into a separate file

I've seen (and tried) a number of suggestions found on here with no success :(

`arsort($propertylist->price);` breaks the code

Here is an excerpt of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
   .......
   <property>
      <propertyID />
      <branchID>1</branchID>
      <clientName>y</clientName>
      <branchName>z</branchName>
      <department>S</department>
      <referenceNumber>1</referenceNumber>
      <price>219950</price>
      <fullDescription><![CDATA[<strong>LOCATION</strong>]]></fullDescription>
      <flags>
         <flag />
      </flags>
      <images>
         <image modified="2014-05-22 11:10:33">http://link.to/image.jpg</image>
      </images>
      <epcFrontPages />
      <brochures>
         <brochure modified="2014-05-22 14:37:38">http://link.to/file.pdf</brochure>
      </brochures>
   </property>
   .......
</properties>
```

Any help very much appreciated

Comment: Could you please add an example of your XML !

Comment: I'm confused as to what you want @Ismail, the page works fine as it is at the moment just unsorted - I can post the whole page code if that will help

Comment: Just  an XML portion, source XML !

Comment: Ok - will post a segment of the file in a moment - will edit it into the original question post

Comment: Is your goal to sort the file in the remote server ?!

Comment: I can't edit the question so here's the excerpt .... Single entry

Comment: Nothing is shown !

Comment: `<properties>
<property>
<propertyID></propertyID>
<branchID>1</branchID>
<clientName>y</clientName>
<branchName>z</branchName>
<department>S</department>
<referenceNumber>1</referenceNumber>
<price>219950</price>
<fullDescription>
<![CDATA[
<strong>LOCATION</strong>
]]>
</fullDescription>
<flags>
<flag></flag>
</flags>
<images>
<image modified="2014-05-22 11:10:33">
http://link.to/image.jpg
</image>
</images>
<epcFrontPages></epcFrontPages>
<brochures>
<brochure modified="2014-05-22 14:37:38">
http://link.to/file.pdf
</brochure>
</brochures>
</property>`

Comment: Had to edit for length :(

Comment: Goal is not to sort on remote server, supplier sorts by propertyID only, we can't save to their server and all access must be made to the original file each time ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
//Read the xml file
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://link.to/file.xml?accesskey");
//Get all properties
$propertylist = $xml->xpath("/properties/property");
//Sort them by price (descending)
usort($propertylist, function($a, $b) {
    return $b->price - $a->price;
});

//Now you can loop through your ordered `$propertylist`:
foreach($propertylist as $property) {
    echo $property->fullDescription . "<br>";
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/Gj120

Comment: needed to make a couple of changes, only minor, juggling variable names to fit with the rest of the page code

Thanks :) :)

Answer (score 0):

control your data to array

```
<?php
$simple = "<para><note>simple note</note></para>";
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $simple, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);
echo "Index array\n";
print_r($index);
echo "\nVals array\n";
print_r($vals);
?>
```

then sort it as array 
[sort array functions](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=sort%20an%20array&scope=quickref)